# Extened ASM and lack of maching operands to name constraints

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, inline-assembly

I have a `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int EAX;
    unsigned int EBX;
    unsigned int ECX;
    unsigned int EDX;
} CPUIDinfo;
```

And that `struct` is used in a function:

```
void get_cpuid_info(CPUIDinfo *info, const unsigned int func, const unsigned int subfunc)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "push %%rax       ;\n"
        "push %%rcx       ;\n"
        "mov %0, %%eax    ;\n"
        "mov %1, %%ecx    ;\n"
        "cpuid            ;\n"
        "mov %%eax, %2    ;\n"
        "mov %%ebx, %3    ;\n"
        "mov %%ecx, %4    ;\n"
        "mov %%edx, %5    ;\n"
        "pop %%rcx        ;\n"
        "pop %%rax        ;\n"

        : "=m"(info->EAX), "=m"(info->EBX), "=m"(info->ECX), "=m"(info->EDX)
        : "m"(func), "m"(subfunc)
        : "%eax", "%ebx", "%ecx", "%edx"
    );
}
```

The assembler is matching the reads correctly (`%0` and `%1`), but its not matching the writes correctly. When writing, its using {`%0`, `%1`, `%2`, `%3`} rather than {`%2`, `%3`, `%4`, `%5`}. That means `info->EAX` gets assigned `func`, `info->EBX` gets assigned `subfunc`, `info->ECX` gets what should have been placed in `info->EAX`, etc.

From the [Extended ASM manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html), I know the assembler has name constraints:

```
"mov %[func],    %%eax    ;\n"
"mov %[subfunc], %%ecx    ;\n"
```

But I receive an error when I try to use them:

```
error: undefined named operand 'func'
error: undefined named operand 'subfunc'
```

I also tried to tell the assembler what to use where:

```
    : [2]"=m"(info->EAX), [3]"=m"(info->EBX), [4]"=m"(info->ECX), [5]"=m"(info->EDX)
    : [0]"m"(func), [1]"m"(subfunc)
    : "%eax", "%ebx", "%ecx", "%edx"
```

But that results in more errors like:

```
error: expected identifier before numeric constant
error: expected ']' before numeric constant
error: expected string-literal before numeric constant
```

How can I match my operands so the writes (e.g., `mov %%eax, %2`) perform as expected?

Comment: You should use the appropriate register constraints and get rid of all the `MOV` instructions.

Comment: Sorry, Jester. I don't understand what you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the proper register constraints, your function could look something like this:

```
void get_cpuid_info(CPUIDinfo *info, const unsigned int func, const unsigned int subfunc)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "cpuid"
        : "=a"(info->EAX), "=b"(info->EBX), "=c"(info->ECX), "=d"(info->EDX)
        : "a"(func), "c"(subfunc)
    );
}
```

But to address your particular problem: the name you want to use should be specified in the constraint. That is instead of `[0]"m"(func), [1]"m"(subfunc)` you should have written:
`[func] "m" (func), [subfunc] "m" (subfunc)` and similarly for the output constraints. The point of this whole business is to get rid of numbers. You should put the symbolic name inside the square brackets, and the value in the round brackets.

Comment: Thanks Jester. This works as expected for both GCC and Clang. So I'm clear: there's no need for a clobber list? (I tried adding `: "a", "b", "c", "d"` and it does not compile).

Comment: That's right, since all of those are outputs. If `cpuid` clobbered something else (that you don't use), you'd have to list that. Oh, and the clobber list uses register names, not constraints, so you'd have to write that as `"eax", "ebx", "ecx", "edx"` anyway.